# Add row at the end of NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I would like to add a new row of the end of my NSTableView.

I tried this code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblPositions: NSTableView!
let values = ["Test 1","Test 2","Test 3","Test 4","Test 5"]

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
   return values.count
}

@IBAction func addRow(_ sender: Any) {
   tblPositions.beginUpdates()
   tblPositions.insertRows(at: IndexSet(integer: 0), withAnimation: .effectFade)
   tblPositions.endUpdates()
}
```

This code works fine. But this add my always a row on the top instead of the end.

Comment: Have you added object in array also?

Comment: you are inserting it at the first position (index: `0`)... of course it is appearing at the top as first item; why didn't you insert the new row at the end of the table as you want...? I don't get your problem here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tblPositions: NSTableView!
let values = ["Test 1","Test 2","Test 3","Test 4","Test 5"]

func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
   return values.count
}

@IBAction func addRow(_ sender: Any) {

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.insertRows(at: IndexSet(integer: values.count - 1), withAnimation: .effectFade)
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: this doesnt' work. the basic command is: `tblPositions.insertRows(at: <IndexSet>, withAnimation: <NSTableViewAnimationOptions>)` index path is not possible there

Comment: i work with swift 3 for macOS. there it doesnt work:  `Cannot convert value of type 'IndexPath' to expected element type 'Int'`

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that your working on a MacOS application. Could you please try it now?